# Derivative in InfinitePolynomialRing

Tags: sage

I am attempting to take a derivative of an element in the class InfinitePolynomialRing. Some digging led me to the following way to do this:

```
X.<p> = InfinitePolynomialRing(QQ)
f= p[3]
f.derivative(f.variables()[f.variables().index(p[3])])
```

So my polynomial is just p_3 and I wish to take it's derivative with respect to p_3. However upon doing so I get the following error:

```
TypeError: provided variable is not in same ring as self
```

Even more bizarre is that the derivative with respect to any other variable works well:

```
X.<p> = InfinitePolynomialRing(QQ)
f=p[1]
f.derivative(f.variables()[f.variables().index(p[1])])
```

Gives me 1, the error only arises for p_3 and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Math Stack Exchange or another Stack Exchange site

Comment: @charlesreid1 Seems to be a question about how to do something in `sage`, which has a valid tag. Why do you think it off-topic?